# DateTime.ParseExact without a delimiter

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have a file with a Date/Time in its filename.

e.g.
201511151515.html
which represents November 15, 2015 15:15

When trying to parse using DateTime.ParseExact

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("201511151515", "yyyyMMddhhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> "String was not recognized as a valid datetime".

Why is ParseExact not correctly parsing the string?  According to what I've read on MSDN, if I supply the custom date mask, the method should be able to correctly parse the string.

MSDN link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Can you post a quote or a link to that MSDN article?

Comment: I would guess the hours portion needs to be HH.  I think hh is 1-12.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot that's the answer

Comment: Thanks Glorin, you were right.  Thanks Soner, I couldn't find that one when searching before I posted.  Suppose I should have looked for TryParseExact along with ParseExact.

Comment: @adamjgp I know, it _can_ be hard to find sometimes when dealing with `DateTİme` parsing. Instead, read _more_ carefully the MSDN page that you linked. Answer is almost always there when dealing with parsing stuff.